# When looking at normals, even when it's a new blend, it looks as if I have duplicate faces

Tags: 3d-view, error, visibility

[image]

New to blender, following and following Udemy tutorial. But my objects always look like they're stacked or duplicated, even after merging vertices. So I created a new blend and added new objects in. Looking at the normals it still looks like like they're all duped even though they're all brand new, including the starting cube, which I didn't delete. I saw another post indicating it could be camera clipping but I played with that and the problem still persists. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: Wow, that was it. Good call.